# three js RingBufferGeometry, update thetaLength

Tags: three.js

i think this is easy to solve but i don't get the solution.
im using a ringbuffergeometry and want to update the thetaLength parameter dynamically. This is my code:

```
var progressGeometry = new THREE.RingBufferGeometry( 230, 240, 40, 6, 1.6, 0.4 );
var ringMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x000000, side: THREE.DoubleSide } ); 
progress = new THREE.Mesh( progressGeometry, ringMaterial );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It needs to re-build a whole geometry dynamically

Our object:

```
var progressGeo = new THREE.RingBufferGeometry(1, 2, 32, null, 0, Math.PI);
var progressMat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0x0000ff});
var progress = new THREE.Mesh(progressGeo, progressMat);
scene.add(progress);
```

and, for example, in the animation loop we'll re-build its geometry:

```
function render(){
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  progress.geometry.dispose(); // dispose our old geometry
  progressGeo = new THREE.RingBufferGeometry(1, 2, 32, null, 0, Math.PI + Math.sin(Date.now() * 0.001) * Math.PI); // build a new geometry
  progress.geometry = progressGeo; // apply the new one
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prisoner849/r23wdtax/) example r86

Comment: You're welcome ) They use this technique in the examples in the documentation