# RingBufferGeometry thetaLength animation with GSAP and react-three-fiber

Tags: three.js, gsap, react-three-fiber

I would like to animate my ringBufferGeometry like in example below, but I would like to  use GSAP to animate this ringBufferGeometry for certain amount of time and I would like then to stop it when the thetaLength will equal to some value. Something like in example below but without the use of Math.sin().

[three js RingBufferGeometry, update thetaLength](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44751130/three-js-ringbuffergeometry-update-thetalength)

This is what I want to achieve(link below), but I want stop to animate when it reaches the full triangle form.

https://jsfiddle.net/02oyunbj/1/

My code

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import App from './App'

function Container(props) {
  return <div style={{ position: 'absolute', inset: 0 }} {...props} />
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Container>
    <App />
  </Container>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

```
import { useRef, useEffect } from 'react'
import { Canvas } from '@react-three/fiber'
import { OrbitControls } from '@react-three/drei'
import * as THREE from 'three'
import gsap from 'gsap'

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Canvas camera={{ position: [0, 0, 15] }}>
      <color attach="background" args={['black']} />
      <OrbitControls />

      <spotLight position={[15, 15, 15]} angle={0.3} color={'white'} />

      <TriangleRing />
    </Canvas>
  )
}

const TriangleRing = () => {
  const triangleRingRef = useRef()

  const parametersObj = {
    innerRadius: 4,
    outerRadius: 8,
    thetaSegments: 1,
    phiSegments: 30,
    thetaStart: 1.55,
    thetaLength: 0,
  }
  const parameters = [
    parametersObj.innerRadius,
    parametersObj.outerRadius,
    parametersObj.thetaSegments,
    parametersObj.phiSegments,
    parametersObj.thetaStart,
    parametersObj.thetaLength,
  ]

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(triangleRingRef.current)
    const triangleGeometry = triangleRingRef.current.geometry

    gsap.set(triangleGeometry, {
      parameters: { ...parametersObj, thetaLength: 0 },
    })
    const tl = gsap.timeline({ defaults: { ease: 'power3.inOut' } })
    tl.to(triangleGeometry, {
      parameters: { ...parametersObj, thetaLength: 6.3 },
      duration: 4,
    })
  })
  return (
    <mesh ref={triangleRingRef}>
      <ringBufferGeometry args={parameters} name="TriangleRing" />
      <meshToonMaterial side={THREE.DoubleSide} color={0xffffff} />
    </mesh>
  )
}
```

Link to sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-lichterman-edpfr?file=/src/App.jsx:0-1517

Answer (score 1):

By default GSAP works in terms of seconds, not velocity or anything like that. So you'll need to calculate how long the tween(s) should run (by using the difference in value and the rate at which you want it to move) to get it to result in the end value that you need.

Without a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it's hard for us to help more at this point.